# Incorrect mountpoint for uWSGI in emperor mode

Tags: nginx, flask, alias, uwsgi

I am setting up emperor mode for several apps on the same domain, where each has a different alias. I almost have it working, but it is not giving the correct mountpoint.

My `emperor.ini` file (in `/etc/uwsgi`) is

```
[uwsgi]
emperor = /etc/uwsgi/vassals
```

And my test vassal config `reg_demo.ini` (in `/etc/uwsgi/vassals`) is:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /usr/share/nginx/wsgi/flask-appbuilder/peds_registry
pyhome = /usr/share/nginx/wsgi/flask-appbuilder/venv
venv = /usr/share/nginx/wsgi/flask-appbuilder/venv
binary-path = /home/gms/Envs/Python/bin/uwsgi
chmod-socket = 666
logto = /etc/uwsgi/test.log
callable = app
module = run
mount: /reg_demo=run.py
socket = /tmp/reg_demo.sock
manage-script-name = true
vacuum = true
env = LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
threads = 1
workers = 4 #can be adjusted
master = true
max-requests = 1000
harakiri = 120
buffer-size = 24576
if-env = VIRTUAL_ENV
virtualenv = %(_)
endif =
```

The defined alias in nginx.conf is:

```
location /reg_demo {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/reg_demo.sock;
    uwsgi_read_timeout 300;
}
```

But, when I fire up uwsgi (`uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini`), my log shows that:

```
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 4 seconds on interpreter 0x23dd840 pid: 16690 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 16690)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 16693, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 16694, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 16695, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 16696, cores: 1)
```

- as opposed to the expected `WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='/reg_demo')` - otherwise, everything else starts up just fine.

And, thus, when I go to the web page for this, `http://hostname/reg_demo`, it 
is all buggered, because it cannot resolve all references based on my mountpoint.[image: Screwy routes on web app munging output]

This works great in non-emperor mode, but alas, I need to be able to deploy multiple apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Ended being a syntax error: I had `mount: /reg_demo=run.py` for some stupid reason when it should have been `mount = /reg_demo=run.py` - what tipped me off was the syntax highlighting in vim...